# Calling Loaded Event of Page From Window C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, events

I have a `Window` that contains a number of `Buttons`, all of which are supposed to display a different `PDF` inside of the `Window`. To do this I use a `Frame` on the `Window` that I display a `Page` in using;

```
private void OnPDFButton1Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    navigationFrame.Navigate(new Uri("View/PDFPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

To display the `PDF` inside the `Page`, I take advantage of it's `Loaded` event;

```
private void OnPageLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var _buttonPathDataService = new ButtonPathDataService();
    try
    {
        var pdfURI = new Uri(_buttonPathDataService.GetButtonPath(Properties.Settings.Default.VideoMode));
        PDFWebBrowser.Navigate(pdfURI);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No PDF linked!");
    }
}
```

The issue I am having with this is say the user has clicked one on `Button` to display a `PDF`, this works fine. However, if the user clicks on another `Button`,  because it is using the same `Page` (PDFPage.xaml) the `OnPageLoad` is never fired due to (quite obviously) the `Page` having already been loaded for the previous `PDF`.

My question is how can I call an event on the `PDFPage`, from my main `Window` that tells the `PDFWebBrowser` to navigate to a new `Uri`? Essentially how would I move the contents of the page's `Loaded` event into a method that can be called on a `Button` click in the `Window`.

Answer (score 1):

Take pdf-load code to another method and call it from another button:

```
private void OnPageLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Load();
} 
public void Load()
{
    var _buttonPathDataService = new ButtonPathDataService();
    try
    {
        var pdfURI = new Uri(_buttonPathDataService.GetButtonPath(Properties.Settings.Default.VideoMode));
        PDFWebBrowser.Navigate(pdfURI);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No PDF linked!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use OnNavigatedTo. I think it is being called every time when user   navigates to that page.

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
        // something to do
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call an event handler from another event handler from another method. Let me show an example:

```
private void YourAnotherButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   OnPageLoad(null, null);
}
```

Your goal is just to set necessary address of PDF file.

Comment: For now I've just got two pages that I intermittently switch between whenever a user clicks a button, but I'll be sure to check this out tomorrow thanks!